# How is a bidirectional non-containment relation modeled within EMF?

Tags: uml, emf

Someone can help me with the question below?

How is a `bidirectional` `non-containment` relation (= “`normal`” association according to `UML 2.0`) modeled within `EMF`?

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to create two classes with that relation and export the EMF.

Answer (score 0):

Create two references a -> b, and b -> a. Then set one reference as the opposite of the other.